# git push останавливается на writing objects

Tags: git, git-push, push

При попытке запушить коммит процесс останавливается на writing objects и ничего больше не происходит, никаких ошибок, вообще ничего. Вот как это выглядит:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects:  66% (16/24)
```

И в таком виде висит бесконечно. Помогите разобраться!

---

`http.postBuffer` помог, но в итоге я получил вот такую ошибку

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 1.69 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 24 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Если `http.postBuffer` не поможет — пишите, будем дальше разбираться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `http.postBuffer` помог, но в итоге я получил вот такую ошибку `$ git push
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 1.69 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 24 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
Everything up-to-date`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, что у вас в репозитории есть очень большой объект. Фильмы или iso-образы дисков не коммитили?

Может помочь увеличение буфера http:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Источники:

- [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6842687/2790048)
- [Git hangs while writing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887228/2790048)

Comment: `http.postBuffer` помог, но в итоге я получил вот такую ошибку `$ git push Counting objects: 24, done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done. Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 1.69 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 24 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: fatal: early EOF fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053 Everything up-to-date`

Comment: @VadikVadik пожалуйста, добавьте этот текст в вопрос. Комментарии сложно читать.